# Authentication of three different login forms in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, multiple-login

In my code, there are three login forms in three different areas, and I want authentication to be done in the three areas in such a way that it is referred to the login form specific to the area.
I wrote the code in the startup, but I don't know what to write in the login function, please guide me. Thank you :)

codes in startup.cs

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie("ProvinceArea", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "ProvinceLevel";
                options.LoginPath = "/Plogin";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Plogout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            }).AddCookie("CountyLevel", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "CountyLevel";
                options.LoginPath = "/Clogin";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Clogout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            }).AddCookie("DistrictLevel", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "DistrictLevel";
                options.LoginPath = "/Dlogin";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Dlogout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

Authentication in three areas named ProvinceArea, CountyArea and DistrictArea and reference to three logn forms specific to each area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pages that need authentication you need to use the `Authorize` attribute and specify the scheme for that area e.g.:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ProvinceArea")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    // ...
}
```

In your login handler use:

```cs
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme, principal);
```

where scheme is `"ProvinceArea"` or `"CountyLevel"` or `"DistrictLevel"` for each login form. Example:

```cs
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "..."),
    new Claim("FullName", "..."),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ProvinceArea");

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("ProvinceArea", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
```

Also you should probably remove these lines:

```cs
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

because you don't have any authentication scheme with the name `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` (this is just a constant string). Your authentication schemes are `"ProvinceArea"`, `"CountyLevel"` and `"DistrictLevel"`.

Check [Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [Create an authentication cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-an-authentication-cookie).

Comment: await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme, principal);
I have a problem with this command because visual studio gets the error of unknown scheme.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Make sure you pass the same string as the one you pass to the `AddCookie` method.

Comment: scheme does not exist in the current context

Comment: `SignInAsync(scheme, principal);` is just the method's signature. You need to pass actual parameters e.g.: `SignInAsync("ProvinceArea", ...);`. Check [Create an authentication cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-an-authentication-cookie).